# Cannot perform Google sign-in using firebase_ui_oauth_google package on iOS device in Flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, google-signin

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' hide EmailAuthProvider;
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_ui_oauth_google/firebase_ui_oauth_google.dart';


late final FirebaseFirestore db;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  ).then((_) {
    print('⭐️fb init success⭐️');
  });

  FirebaseUIAuth.configureProviders([
    GoogleProvider(
      //what should i write here?
      // clientId: 'com.googleusercontent.apps.******************************', //(A)Reverse client id of iOS
      // clientId:'******************************.apps.googleusercontent.com',//(B)firebase console web apps clientID
      clientId:'******************************.apps.googleusercontent.com', //client id of iOS
    ),
    EmailAuthProvider(),
  ]);

  db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticationWrapperState createState() => _AuthenticationWrapperState();
}

class _AuthenticationWrapperState extends State<AuthenticationWrapper> {
  // final providers = [
  //   EmailAuthProvider(),
  // ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    if (user == null) {
      return SignInScreen(
        // providers: providers,
        actions: [
          AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, state) {
            setState(() {});
          }),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return HomePage(
        onSignOut: () {
          setState(() {});
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_oauth_google

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_auth

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Flutter/blob/main/packages/firebase_ui_auth/doc/providers/oauth.md

I wrote the above code using the above page as a reference and tried running it on an actual iOS device, but no matter how many times I try it, the following error occurs.
(The Google sign-in button is displayed on the screen, but the moment I press it, the app is forced to close and the following error occurs.)
(email-password sign-in works fine.)

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes: com.googleusercontent.apps.******************************'
```

I'm really confused, am I doing something wrong?

Can firebase_ui_oauth_google be used at this time?

What should I set as the GoogleProvider constructor argument?

(A)https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in#ios-integration

(B)https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Flutter/blob/main/packages/firebase_ui_auth/doc/providers/oauth.md#google-sign-in